# overload class functions in c++?

Tags: c++, overloading

I am trying to overload functions that are under a class but I will be passing different data types to the functions. The values passed to it can either be `int` or `char`depending on the input. But I am totally confused how to go with it. Here are my function definitions and main function.

```
    int main()        
    {
                int pushInt;
                char pushInt;
                cout<<"\n\nEnter Number: ";
                cin >> pushInt;
                mainClassStack.pushNumber(pushInt);
                break;
            }

void stack_class::pushNumber(int numberFunc)
{
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head = new stack_struct;
        head->number = numberFunc;
        head->next_number = NULL;
        tailPointer=head;
    }
    else
    {
        pointerFunc = new stack_struct;
        pointerFunc->number=numberFunc;
        pointerFunc->next_number=NULL;
        head->next_number=pointerFunc;
        head=pointerFunc;
    }
}


void stack_class::pushNumber(char charFunc)
{

    int a=0;
    a= charFunc;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head = new stack_struct;
        head->number = a;
        head->next_number = NULL;
        tailPointer=head;
    }
    else
    {
        pointerFunc = new stack_struct;
        pointerFunc->number=a;
        pointerFunc->next_number=NULL;
        head->next_number=pointerFunc;
        head=pointerFunc;
    }

}
```

and if you need my class definition, here it it

```
class stack_class
{
private:

    struct stack_struct *head;

public:
    stack_class();//constructor
    ~stack_class();//destructor
    void pushNumber(int number);
    void pushNumber(char number);
    void pushNumber(int *number);
    void popNumber();
    void findNumber();
    void clearStack();
    void sizeFinder();
    void printStack();
    void reverseStack();//Extra Credit
};

stack_class mainClassStack;

stack_struct *pointerFunc,*tailPointer=NULL,*pointerFunc3,*printPointer;
```

I tried to compile, but program freezes when I try to run this through the compiler. Any suggestions what should I do?

Comment: What do you mean, "program freezes when you run it through the compiler" ? We need more details about your problem. Is it a compilation error (in that case, provide said error), or a runtime failure (give more details as well) ?

Comment: freezing is happening during compiling or at runtime?

Comment: @Nbr44 like the program doesn't do anything. Well, I just fixed it actually. But now when I try to pass integer values, for some reason it converts the int value to an ascii value and adds the ascii value to the list.

Comment: @shivakumar at runtime. This is a part of a program and this part corresponds `option 1`. When I press `option 1`, the program freezes at runtime.

Comment: Is this code even compiling ? You have two variables named the same way (`int pushInt` and `char pushInt`).

Comment: @Nbr44 that is exactly where my problem is. `pushInt` can be either `int` or `char` which will be passed into the corresponding function depending on the input.

Comment: Ah, I see - the problem is clearer now. In that case, I think the easiest would be to store your input in a `std::string`, analyze it, and see whether or not you want to interpret it as an `int` or a `char`. I don't think there's a way of doing this the way you want, `std::cin` can only be given one variable to store the result in.